# Is it possible to have a Swift protocol that enforces static method and not class method or vice versa?

Tags: swift3, protocols

Is it possible to have a Swift protocol that enforces static method and not class method or vice versa?

For example class func or final class func are not allowed even though the protocol is set to be a class protocol:

```
protocol MyProtocol: class {
    final class func dummyClassMethod()
}
```

Or in this case, a class is allowed to create a static method OR a class method when conforming to this:

```
protocol MyProtocol: class {
    static func dummyClassMethod()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, because the apple's docs says explicitly to use only `static` for this purpose:

> To declare a `class` or `static` method requirement in a **protocol**
>   declaration, **mark the method declaration with the `static` declaration**
>   **modifier**.

Source: [Protocol Method Declaration](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH34-ID483)

---

When you implement the `static` method of the `protocol` in your `class`, there is no difference in using `class` or `static` in your implementation.

```
protocol ProtocolForClasses: class {
  static func method()
}

class ClassOne: ProtocolForClasses {
  class func method() {

  }
}

class ClassTwo: ProtocolForClasses {
  static func method() {

  }
}
```

Comment: "there is no difference in using `class` or `static` in your implementation" → There is actually a difference as `static` methods cannot be overridden in subclasses whereas `class` methods can.